# Import and use untyped leaflet JS plugin with Typescript 2 in Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, typescript-typings

I'm using LeafletJS library in Angular 2 application. The library itself is working fine since I've included the type definition (leaflet.d.ts) and of course the leaflet node module.

I'm trying to import a plugin for the leaflet library called "[leaflet-canvasicon](https://github.com/sashakavun/leaflet-canvasicon)" and there is no available type definition for it and since it's written in ES5 whenever I try to include it, the compiler is satisfied, yet I recieve the following error at the console:

```
leaflet-src.js:314
Uncaught TypeError: this.callInitHooks is not a function
    at Object.NewClass (http://localhost:2080/main.bundle.js:58716:8)
    at http://localhost:2080/main.bundle.js:77650:180
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:2080/main.bundle.js:77652:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:2080/inline.js:53:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:2080/main.bundle.js:54476:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:2080/inline.js:53:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:2080/main.bundle.js:54411:90)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:2080/inline.js:53:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:2080/main.bundle.js:54600:70)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:2080/inline.js:53:30)
```

**I thought of many solutions**:

- Make a new type definition for the plugin (`leaflet-canvasicon.d.ts`) and use the namespace declaration merging feature in Typescript in order to still use the plugin as `L.CanvasIcon`
- Rewrite the plugin using typescript extending the existing interfaces in `namespace L`.
- Stop using the typed 'leaflet' and just import the node module written in ES5 then add L declaration in angular's `typings.d.ts` file:  `declare var L: any;`

**But every time I face compiler issues. I think I'm doing it wrong. How can I include the plugin, keep the compiler satisfied and be able to use it as `L.CanvasIcon`**

Here is `package.json` file:

```
 "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/core": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/forms": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/http": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/router": "3.1.2",
        "@types/leaflet": "^1.0.36",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "leaflet": "^1.0.1",
        "leaflet-canvasicon": "^0.1.6",
        "leafletjs-canvas-overlay": "^1.0.1",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.1",
        "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
        "zone.js": "^0.6.26"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.19-3",
        "ts-node": "1.6.1",
        "tslint": "3.15.1",
        "typescript": "2.0.6",
        "typings": "^1.5.0"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is runtime error not related to missing typings. The problem is related to `leaflet` version mismatch.

It seems that `leaflet-canvasicon` is designed for older versions of `leaflet`. Try to fallback to `leaflet` with version `0.7.x`.

```
 "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/core": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/forms": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/http": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/router": "3.1.2",
        "@types/leaflet": "0.7.x",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "leaflet": "0.7.x", // note the change
        "leaflet-canvasicon": "^0.1.6",
        "leafletjs-canvas-overlay": "^1.0.1",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.1",
        "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
        "zone.js": "^0.6.26"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.19-3",
        "ts-node": "1.6.1",
        "tslint": "3.15.1",
        "typescript": "2.0.6",
        "typings": "^1.5.0"
      }
    }
```

For the future, you can remember that `this.callInitHooks is not a function` is **typical problem** after loading old extensions to `leaflet` version >=1

Comment: yes, it works after falling back to `leaflet 0.7` version. yet **type definition** is still needed to use it within the same namespace as `L.CanvasIcon`.

Comment: How did you manage the type definition needed for using the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Import this file after leaflet if you need to use leaflet plugins in typescript.

```ts
declare module L {
    // plugins that extend Class i.e L.MyClass
    export let MyClass:any;
    // plugins that uses class factory i.e myClass
    export let myClass:any;

   //plugins that extend Control comes here i.e L.Control.Navbar
   export namespace Control {
      export let Navbar: any;
   }
   // plugins that have control factories come here i.e. L.control.navbar
  export namespace control {
     export let navbar: any;
  }

  //plugins that extend Layer comes here i.e L.Layer.NewLayer
   export namespace Layer {
      export let NewLayer: any;
   }
  // plugins that have layer factories come here i.e. L.layer.newLayer
  export namespace layer {
     export let newLayer: any;
  }
  //plugins that extend Handler comes here i.e. L.Handler.NewHandler
   export namespace Handler {
      export let NewHandler: any;
   }
  // plugins that have handler factories come here i.e. L.Handler.newHandler
  export namespace handler {
     export let newHandler: any;
  }
}
```

You can be explicit with the types if you want to.

Comment: Hello, what do you do if you get an error that complains like "typeerror: L.Control.LinearCore is not a constructor"? I've added your code with my variable names, but is there another bit that is needed if my plugin expects a constructor?